# Use Literal[] strings in an overload python

Tags: python, overloading, mypy

I have a factory function taking a string and returning different objects based on that - e.g.

```
def get_object(clsid:str) -> object:
    if clsid == "Foo":
        return Foo()
    elif clsid == "Bar":
        return Bar()
    elif ...
```

<sub>That's pseudocode - in reality I'm using win32com EnsureDispatch to get a com object from its clsid</sub>

I want to use mypy's `Literal` type to say if clsid is "Foo" then Foo type will be returned, otherwise default to object. However I tried:

```
@overload
def get_object(clsid:Literal["Foo"]) -> Foo: ...

def get_object(clsid:str) -> object:
    ... # concrete implementation
```

but what I really need is

```
@overload
def get_object(clsid:str AND NOT (Literal["Foo"] | Literal["Bar"]) ) -> object: ...
@overload
def get_object(clsid:Literal["Foo"]) -> Foo: ...
@overload
def get_object(clsid:Literal["Bar"]) -> Bar: ...
def get_object(clsid:str) -> object: #concrete
```

I guess I could make the concrete only accept `Literal["Foo"]|Literal["Bar"]` and then add more options as I need them rather than accepting all `str`s but IDK what's idiomatic here?

Comment: Based on this: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/253 , type checkers might be happy if you just from top to bottom use the most specific ones first, e.g. first the Literals, then the rest..